# How to: paper design to photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've a Wacom Bamboo Fun Touch & Pen to draw on the PC. I also have some old designs drawed on paper that I want to draw on the PC using Photoshop. The problem is that the paper design is bigger than the drawable surface of the graphics tablet. I want to redraw the designs overlapping the paper on the tablet, so that I can trace the design. So, my question is: How can achieve this?

I've tried slicing the paper using a pencil and redraw the designs little by little, part by part, but the final result is awful...

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Since you already have the drawing, why not just scan it in?

Comment: As @DA01 points out - scan your drawing. If it takes several scans you can bring the images together in photoshop and use the *difference* blend mode to match them up, do any other curves/contrast adjustments you need to make it easy to tracer over than bring the file into Illustrator to vectorize over

Comment: Yes! Great idea! I didn't think in it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlanGilbertson done!

Comment: @DA01 ... and voted for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the drawing, I would suggest scanning it in.